# restore table and populate new data from transaction log

Tags: mysql, replication, restore, mysqldump

I use `mysqldump` nightly to backup a database. I'm trying to find a way to do a partial restore on the data from one table. I use the `--master-data` flag so I know where in the transactions log my data was at the generation. Is there a command I can run for my one table to populate from X in the the logs to the current log position?

There already is a slave process running on this machine. I'm trying to create this as a second table with a similar name do run some tests with.

Answer (score 0):

You're restored a table to a different name and you want to run replication against that table?

Given replication filters that change mapping between master/slave table names are global, you'll need a separate slave instance to test against this table. Once you do this, you don't even need replication filters again to test the new table structure.